# Copyrights for translated poems

Tags: translations

I've over the years translated to Arabic more than 40 short quotes from poems of contemporary and classical poets, and I would like to publish as a collection (in Arabic). Would that be considered fair use of the original poems? What if I also included the original parts (in English)? Or is it safer to just provide links?

Thanks,

Comment: What would the purpose of the collection be? (e.g. teaching material, an analysis of poetic styles, simple poetry appreciation?) Would this be for profit or non-profit purposes? How would it be published, and where? All these factors can affect "fair use".

Comment: I did it for fun but now that I have 40 or so pieces I thought I would bundle them together and publish the resulting book on my blog. I won't be it and I do not advertise on my blog.

Comment: Closing this as there is no apparent connection to academia. It **may** be on-topic on [writing.se] or – in a generalised form, without seeking individual advice – on [law.se]. Either way, you’ll probably need to provide more details.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the right to translate is reserved to the copyright holder, so your best option is to seek permission.

Fair use varies around the world, though. When applicable it generally depends on how much you use, the purpose, and whether what you do affects the value of the original to the copyright holder.

But translation for translation sake is probably especially risky.

Not seeking permission could put you at risk and publishers will normally be wary. But if you get permission it could greatly enhance what you can do.

Note also, that if the work is old enough (early 20th century and earlier) it is likely out of copyright so "fair use" is no longer a concern.

Comment: Thanks @Buffy. That was my concern. I am not sure that I am motivated enough/have the resources to seek permission. So I might it just keep the collection private.